# Setting and modifying date/time on the x axis

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, time, axis

I am looking at plotting date/time data on a graph and I cannot get the x axis ticks/values to where I want them. I have tried so many solutions and nothing seems to work. I am also a novice and very unfamiliar with a lot of packages relevant to date/time so the simpler/clearer the explanation the better please.

[image]
These are the graphs(using the same code for both) which are produced and you can see the x axis is completely different, and the last tick on the graph on the left is not even legible. I am trying to plot water quality data (for a specific pesticide) across two sampling occasions.
The code I am using is as follows:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
library(readr)

PCD <- read_csv("PC.csv") %>% 
  mutate(date_timed  = dmy_hms(paste(Dated, as.character(Timed), sep=" ")))

PCd <- ggplot(data=PCD, aes(x=date_timed, y=Vald)) +  
  geom_smooth(color = "bisque4") +  
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line(aes(y = GVd), color="steelblue", linetype="longdash") +
  theme_bw() + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 0.15)) + 
  labs(y= "Concentration (µg/L)", x = "Sample Date", title = "Event 2") + 
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(face = "bold", size = 11)) + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(face = "bold", size = 11)) + 
  theme(plot.title =  element_text(face = "bold", size = 11))
PCd

PCD2 <- read_csv("PC.csv") %>% 
  mutate(date_timed2  = dmy_hms(paste(Dated2, as.character(Timed2), sep=" ")))

PCd2 <- ggplot(data=PCD2, aes(x=date_timed2, y=Vald2)) + 
  geom_smooth(color = "bisque4") + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line(aes(y = GVd2), color="steelblue", linetype="longdash") +
  theme_bw() + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 0.10)) + 
  labs(y= "Concentration (µg/L)", x = "Sample Date", title = "Event 2") + 
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(face = "bold", size = 11)) + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(face = "bold", size = 11)) + 
  theme(plot.title =  element_text(face = "bold", size = 11)) + 
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank())
PCd2

figurePCd <- ggarrange(PCd, PCd2,ncol = 2, nrow = 1)
figurePCd <- annotate_figure(figurePCd,top = text_grob("Diazinon concentrations during rainfall events 2020", face = "bold"))
figurePCd
```

Not really looking to simplify the code (I realise I could use functions and make things a lot simpler etc.) because this makes it a lot easier for me to follow and if a problem occurs its easier for me to pinpoint. I just want to know how to fix the x axis labels/scale so that the values plotted on the graph actually have a tick underneath (so that people can see clearly what date and time it was sampled) and have both axis the same. I have tried using scale_x_date and `scale_x_datetime` (limits etc..) which haven't produced what I want so I either dont understand them well enough or they aren't applicable for my situation.

My data is currently set in a csv file as follows:

```
DateP         TimeP      ValP    GVP      DateP2      TimeP2     ValP2  GVP2
29/01/2020  10:45:00 AM  0.14   0.059   24/02/2020  10:15:00 AM  0.06   0.059
3/02/2020   9:40:00 AM   0.06   0.059   26/02/2020  9:45:00 AM   0.05   0.059
```

Likewise the closest I got using `scale_x_datetime` (on a single graph to test) was using the following code:

```r
PCP3 <- read_csv("PlaneCreek.csv") %>%
  mutate(date_timeP3  = dmy_hms(paste(DateP3, as.character(TimeP3),     sep=" ")))

lims <- as.POSIXct(strptime(c("04-03-2020 09:45","10-03-2020 14:05"), format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M"))

PCp3 <- ggplot(data=PCP3, aes(x=as.POSIXct(date_timeP3), y=ValP3)) +  
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line(aes(y = GVP3), color="steelblue", linetype="longdash") +
  theme_bw() + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 0.15)) + 
  labs(y= "Concentration (µg/L)", x = "Sample Date", title = "Event 1") + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank()) + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank()) + 
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(face = "bold", size = 11)) + 
  theme(plot.title =  element_text(face = "bold", size = 11)) + 
  scale_x_datetime(limits = lims)
PCp3
```

however that returned the following graph which hasn't fixed the problem of knowing what date/time each value corresponds to, and there's a lot of white space each side.

[image]

Comment: Please show what you tried with `scale_x_datetime` and the results, as that is typically the canonical solution to this (frequent) question. Also include some usable data. Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Comment: @r2evans I added a bit more context hopefully with one of the examples which scale_x_datetime produced. Otherwise I cannot remember exactly what I did, like i said I tried a lot of options and none worked so I didn't record all options. I don't mind if people make suggestions which I have already tried, I might have done it wrong anyway as I said I am a novice and don't know much.

Comment: I've suggested some edits to the code, mostly so that we don't have to scroll *right* just to see your code for `scale_x_datetime`, and while I was there I added some non-base packages I think you're using. If any of my edits are incorrect or not to your liking, my apologies, feel free to rollback.

Comment: Your call to `scale_x_datetime` only sets `limits=`, have you looked into changing `breaks=` and/or `labels=`? Nothing in your code here suggests you're telling `ggplot2` how to format them nor where to place ticks/labels. [`?scale_x_datetime`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_date.html) is informative and mentions that you can set literal values for them or provide a function to do it *programmatically* (based on the actual limits of the plot); the latter is almost always my preference.